# Fresh Install Linux with Encryption won't boot

Tags: debian, encryption, citrix

I having a problem whereby after I fresh install Debian and enable encryption (Encrypted LVM), it won't boot into the OS, just seeing a black screen.

For a test, I also installed Debian without enabling encryption and it boots into the OS no problems.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably waiting for you to type the encryption password. Some combinations of monitor and video cards have this behaviour.

Just type the password and press `enter`, it should boot.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought it was super strange.
I should report that bug